# Dynamic forms link to report

Tags: reporting, dynamic

The upgrade to dynamic layouts is great, but I can't figure out how to generate a parameterized value now.  I used to be able to use:

```
https://mydomain.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Report/[ReportID]/view?queryScope=userFolders&fv0=[AccountID]
```

... which I'm assuming I could embed in a Rich Text component, could I not?

Simply put, I want to run a report on an object, filtered by the Account I'm currently viewing by passing the AccountID as a filter value (which works, hardcoded).

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](/tour). Including a [Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.